# how to access index path of the collectionview into tableview

Tags: ios, swift, collections, tableview

I have a collectionview and tableview in the viewcontroller. The collectionview contains the collection of chefs and it is situated in the top of the screen.Collection view is horizontally scrolling.
Tableview contains the food offer by the chefs.
The problem is Tableview shows all the dishes offer by all chefs.
I want to show only the selected chef's food in the tableview.

**I want to pass the same indexpath of the collectionview to the tableview view how to achieve this . as both the arrays that I am using are the part of the same structure**

My code is below:

extension MenuViewController : UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    
         return menuArray1.count
     }
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let  cell = menuTableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MenuTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? MenuTableViewCell
    cell?.menuNameLabel.text = menuArray1[indexPath.row].prodName
    cell?.discountLabel.text = menuArray1[indexPath.row].offerPercent
    cell?.menuQuantityLabel.text = menuArray1[indexPath.row].menuDescription
    cell?.originalPriceLabel.text = menuArray1[indexPath.row].originalPrice
    cell?.discountPriceLabel.text = menuArray1[indexPath.row].sellingPrice
    cell?.vegNonVegImageview.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "veg_thumb")
    cell?.menuImage.setImageFromURl(stringImageUrl: menuArray1[indexPath.row].prodImg)
    cell?.timeToDeliverLabel.text = menuArray1[indexPath.row].preparationTime
  //  cell?.menuImage.setImageFromURl(stringImageUrl: menuArray[indexPath.row].prodImg)

    
    cell?.menuImage.setImageFromURl(stringImageUrl: menuArray1[indexPath.row].prodImg)
    cell?.addButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
    cell?.addButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor

    cell?.selectionStyle = .none

       return cell!
   }
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
```

//        return self.view.frame.height * 0.33
return self.view.frame.height * 0.12

```
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     print("chiefFlag\(chiefFlag)")
}
```

}
collection view code:

extension MenuViewController : UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource{

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return addvenderArray.count
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "menuCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath)
    as! menuCollectionViewCell
    
    
    menuTableview.reloadData()
    
    cell.nameLabel.text = addvenderArray[indexPath.row].venderName
    cell.profileImage.setImageFromURl(stringImageUrl: addvenderArray[indexPath.row].vendorImg)
    cell.ratingLabel.text = addvenderArray[indexPath.row].rating
    cell.ratingImageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "chef_rating")
    cell.profileImage.makeCircular()
   
    cell.profileImage.backgroundColor = .white
    
    **var obj = addvenderArray[indexPath.row]
    self.menuArray1 = obj.menu
    menuTableview.reloadData()**
  

  **// Above code is my logic  addvenderArray structure contains the menuArray1.But it gets null value**
    
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("")
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Create a array with particular data model instance you want to sent to the table view.**

**When this required screen appears after api call send first index data to that array and reload table view.**

In the

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

     return "Your array .count"
 }
```

On collectionView **didSelect** delegate method send the data from **addvenderArray[indexPath.row]** to **"Your Array"** and reload the tableview.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let  cell = menuTableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MenuTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? MenuTableViewCell
cell?.menuNameLabel.text = YourArray[indexPath.row].prodName
```

}

YourArray must get instance from that **dishes and offer struct**

Answer (score 0):

looks like you just need to move this code

```
var obj = addvenderArray[indexPath.row]
self.menuArray1 = obj.menu
menuTableview.reloadData()
```

into your didDeselectRowAt method of the collection view